# phpmyadmin is not working #2002 access denied in wamp server

Tags: php

I have get into this problem for the past 3 days i have tried with many options like changing the port and deleting the file mysql-bin.index and even tried to start the services manually also..am unable to restart the services of mysql i n my wamp..
in mysql log file i get the errors as

```
140827 15:09:03 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
140827 15:09:03 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
140827 15:09:03 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
140827 15:09:03 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
140827 15:09:03 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
140827 15:09:03 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
InnoDB: The first specified data file .\ibdata1 did not exist:
InnoDB: a new database to be created!
140827 15:09:03  InnoDB: Setting file .\ibdata1 size to 10 MB
InnoDB: Database physically writes the file full: wait...
140827 15:09:03  InnoDB: Log file .\ib_logfile0 did not exist: new to be created
InnoDB: Setting log file .\ib_logfile0 size to 5 MB
InnoDB: Database physically writes the file full: wait...
140827 15:09:03  InnoDB: Log file .\ib_logfile1 did not exist: new to be created
InnoDB: Setting log file .\ib_logfile1 size to 5 MB
InnoDB: Database physically writes the file full: wait...
InnoDB: Doublewrite buffer not found: creating new
InnoDB: Doublewrite buffer created
InnoDB: 127 rollback segment(s) active.
InnoDB: Creating foreign key constraint system tables
InnoDB: Foreign key constraint system tables created
140827 15:09:04  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
140827 15:09:05 InnoDB: 1.1.8 started; log sequence number 0
140827 15:09:06 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '(null)'; port: 3306
```

plz help me on his as soon as possible...

Comment: I don't see anything that's an error there, just normal log entries. That said, apart from phpmyadmin, can you use the commandline to connect to the DB?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your alias directory to PHPMYADMIN is created in apache in wamp server. Did you recently change your apache configuration or installed a new version of apache?